# the angle between two quaternion vectors is equal to half the angle between their corresponding 3D orientations

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I have read in several sources, such as [this Math Stack Exchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90098/447986) and [these slides from a computer animation class (p. 44)](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi18/cse169-a/slides/CSE169_03.pdf), that given two quaternions $\mathbf{q}_1, \mathbf{q}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^4$, the angle between the 4D quaternion vectors is equal to half the angle between their corresponding 3D orientations. In other words, letting $\mathbf{R}_1, \mathbf{R}_2 \in SO(3)$ denote the rotation matrices corresponding to $\mathbf{q}_1$ and $\mathbf{q}_2$ respectively, the angle between $\mathbf{q}_1$ and $\mathbf{q}_2$ is half the angle of rotation required to get from $\mathbf{R}_1$ to $\mathbf{R}_2$ (the "geodesic distance"). Note that due to the fact that the maximum angle between any 3D orientations is $\pi$, I believe this fact only holds when the angle between the 4D quaternion vectors is less than or equal to $\pi/2$.

I have done an exhaustive search and can't find any proof of why this is true. So I'm looking for proof.

---

**my best insight/attempt:**

So far, I have only been able to prove this fact for the case in which $\mathbf{q}_2$ equals the identity quaternion. Start by writing out the quaternions vectors in terms of axis-angles, where $\theta_1$ and $\mathbf{e}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the angle and axis of $\mathbf{q}_1$, and $\theta_2$ and $\mathbf{e}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the angle and axis of $\mathbf{q}_2$. We have
$$
\mathbf{q}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_1/2) \\ \sin(\theta_1/2) \mathbf{e}_1 \end{bmatrix}, ~~~
\mathbf{q}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_2/2) \\ \sin(\theta_2/2) \mathbf{e}_2 \end{bmatrix} .
$$
Taking the dot product  and using that fact that the quaternions are unit length, we can solve for the angle $\phi$ between the 4D quaternion vectors:
$$
\begin{align}
\cos \phi &= \frac{\mathbf{q}_1 \cdot \mathbf{q}_2}{\lVert \mathbf{q}_1 \rVert \lVert \mathbf{q}_2 \rVert} \\
&= \cos(\theta_1/2) \cos(\theta_2/2) + \mathbf{e}_1 \cdot \mathbf{e}_2 \sin(\theta_1/2) \sin(\theta_2/2) .
\end{align}
$$
If $\mathbf{q}_2$ is taken as the identity quaternion, we have $\theta_2 = 0$ and $\mathbf{q}_2 = [1 ~~ 0 ~~ 0 ~~ 0]^T$, and the equation above becomes
$$
\begin{align}
\cos \phi &= \cos(\theta_1/2) .
\end{align}
$$
Since we have defined $\phi$ to be non-negative, for $-\pi \leq \theta_1 \leq \pi$ we have $\phi = | \theta_1/2 |$. So this seems to offer some insight, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "angle of rotation required to get from $R_1$ to $R_2$" you mean simply the by angle which $R_2{R_1}^{-1}$ rotates around its axis. But this is the same as the angle to rotate the identity frame to $R_2{R_1}^{-1}$, because both transitions between frames are achieved by the same rotation, $R_2{R_1}^{-1}$!

And similarly, the angle between quaternions $q_1$ and $q_2$ is the same as the angle between $1$ and $q_2{q_1}^{-1}$, because multiplying by a unit quaternion is a 4D isometry. But then, the quaternion $q_2{q_1}^{-1}$ corresponds to the rotation $R_2{R_1}^{-1}$... so if you say

> I have only been able to prove this fact for the case in which $q_2$ equals the identity

then you're already done.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines. So I understand that applying a rotation to two quaternions $\mathbf{q}_1$ and $\mathbf{q}_2$ in 4D will not change the angle between them. But in applying that rotation, why can you say that the angle between their corresponding orientations $\mathbf{R}_1$ and $\mathbf{R}_2$ won't change?

Comment: @Trevor The premise here is that the "angle" between the orientations $R_1$ and $R_2$ is $R_2R_1^{-1}$. Do you have a different definition in mind? If you accept that definition, then by definition the angle between $R_1$ and $R_2$ is the same as the angle between the identity rotation and $R_2R_1^{-1}$.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, that is the definition of angle I intended. I think it makes more sense now. So to reiterate, before $\mathbf{q}_1$ and $\mathbf{q}_2$ are rotated, they had a net orientation of $\mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1^{-1}$. After rotating the quaternions, they still have a net orientation of $\mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1^{-1}$, which proves that the angle between orientations does not change when rotating the quaternions.